# How can I print the decimal representation of a unicode string?

Tags: python, string, unicode

I am trying to compare unicode strings in Python. Since a lot of the symbols look similar and some may contain non-printable characters, I am having trouble debugging where my comparisons are failing.  Is there a way to take a string of unicode characters and print their unicode codes? i.e.:

```
>>> unicode_print('❄')
'\u2744'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can encode that string with some other encoding:

```
>>> s = '❄'
>>> s.encode() # "utf8" by default
b'\xe2\x9d\x84'
```

And for the output you specified, I just found this from [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings):

```
>>> s.encode("unicode_escape")
b'\\u2744'
```